# Odds Ratio for different levels besides reference

Tags: sas

How do you get confidence intervals for odd ratios comparing different groups besides the reference?

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to re-run the model with a different referent group.  Otherwise, there is no easy way to do this in SAS.  You could apply the Delta Method and do it by hand with the beta coefficients and standard errors.

If you are using a Class statement to create different groups, you can use formats and an `ORDER=FORMATTED` option in the PROC statement (depending on the procedure you are using for the regression - this works in genmod). To be sure about which group is the referent.

If you are using disjoint indicator variables in your model, just re-run the model with a different indicator left out.